# Django not serving static files in deployment server

Tags: django, nginx, django-2.1

I know this has been discussed before but nothing worked for me,

I deployed my first Django app yesterday with Nginx and gunicorn but sadly it is not serving the static files.

I have gone through every answer to the same problem but I couldn't find the way out.

Probably I am doing something wrong.

I am on django 2.1

all my static files are under `project/static`

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

I haven't mentioned any static dir because all the files are in static only.

urls.py ( is it necessary in deployment? )

```
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

nginx.confg

```
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias /root/project/projectname/static;
    }
```

my project is in root/project
I don't know if it is a good practice or not I am quite a novice in this.

Comment: You can check your nginx configuration with `nginx -t` command. Have you performed `collectstatic`? Nginx doesn't search all your static folders, just the `STATIC_ROOT` and all your static files should be gathered there with `collectstatic`.

Comment: thanks sir, nginx block rule are perfect and the static files are already in static folder I have uploaded them through ftp I have run collect static too but in front enf I can't see the change

Comment: Both the `location` and `alias` values should have a trailing `/` or neither have a trailing `/`. And in your case you should use `root /root/project/projectname;` instead of `alias` as [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias).

Comment: Tried  but didn't worked I am rebuilding my server using this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Check the nginx error logs. It might be a permission issue. You must make sure the nginx user has read+execute permission for the directory and all parent directories of `/root/project/projectname/static`. (also remember to run django-admin collectstatic)